# How to get Graph (or GraphDef) from a given Model?

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, keras, model

I have a big model defined using Tensorflow 2 with Keras.
The model works well in Python. Now, I want to import it into C++ project.

Inside my C++ project, I use `TF_GraphImportGraphDef` function.
It works well if I prepare `*.pb` file using the following code:

```
    with open('load_model.pb', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph().as_graph_def().SerializeToString())
```

I've tried this code on a simple network written using Tensorflow 1 (using tf.compat.v1.* functions). It works well.

Now I want to export my big model (mentioned at the beginning, written using Tensorflow 2) to the C++ project. To do this, I need to get a `Graph` or `GraphDef` object from my model. The question is: how to do this? I didn't find any property or function to get it.

I've also tried to use `tf.saved_model.save(model, 'model')` to save the whole model. It generates a directory with different files including `saved_model.pb` file. Unfortunately, when I try to load this file in C++ using `TF_GraphImportGraphDef` function, the program throws an exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The protocol buffers file generated by [`tf.saved_model.save`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/saved_model/save) does not contain a [`GraphDef`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.3.0/tensorflow/core/framework/graph.proto) message, but a [`SavedModel`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.3.0/tensorflow/core/protobuf/saved_model.proto). You could [traverse that `SavedModel` in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62812228/1782792) to get the embedded graph(s) in it, but that would not immediately work as a frozen graph, so getting it right would probably be difficult. Instead of that, the C++ API now includes a [`LoadSavedModel`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.3.0/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.h#L99-L120) call that allows you to load a whole saved model from a directory. It should look some like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <...>  // Add necessary TF include directives

using namespace std;
using namespace tensorflow;

int main()
{
    // Path to saved model directory
    const string export_dir = "...";
    // Load model
    Status s;
    SavedModelBundle bundle;
    SessionOptions session_options;
    RunOptions run_options;
    s = LoadSavedModel(session_options, run_options, export_dir,
                       // default "serve" tag set by tf.saved_model.save
                       {"serve"}, &bundle));
    if (!.ok())
    {
        cerr << "Could not load model: " << s.error_message() << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    // Model is loaded
    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

From here, you could do different things. Maybe you would be most comfortable converting that saved model into a frozen graph, using [`FreezeSavedModel`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.3.0/tensorflow/cc/tools/freeze_saved_model.h#L26-L39), which should allow you to do things pretty much as you were doing them before:

```cpp
GraphDef frozen_graph_def;
std::unordered_set<string> inputs;
std::unordered_set<string> outputs;
s = FreezeSavedModel(bundle, &frozen_graph_def,
                     &inputs, &outputs));
if (!s.ok())
{
    cerr << "Could not freeze model: " << s.error_message() << endl;
    return -1;
}
```

Otherwise, you can work directly with the saved model object:

```cpp
// Default "serving_default" signature name set by tf.saved_model_save
const SignatureDef& signature_def = bundle.GetSignatures().at("serving_default");
// Get input and output names (different from layer names)
// Key is input and output layer names
const string input_name = signature_def.inputs().at("my_input").name();
const string output_name = signature_def.inputs().at("my_output").name();
// Run model
Tensor input = ...;
std::vector<Tensor> outputs;
s = bundle.session->Run({{input_name, input}}, {output_name}, {}, &outputs));
if (!s.ok())
{
    cerr << "Error running model: " << s.error_message() << endl;
    return -1;
}
// Get result
Tensor& output = outputs[0];
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I have already tried LoadSavedModel. Unfortunatelly, there is no such declaration in include files provided in installation package here: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c. I suppose that there is no such function in the provided library too.

Comment: @IvanBychkov Ah, so if you are using the C API, yes, that function is not there as such, but you have [`TF_LoadSessionFromSavedModel`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.3.0/tensorflow/c/c_api.h#L1206-L1223), which should do the equivalent thing.

Comment: You also need the following header: `<tensorflow/cc/tools/freeze_saved_model.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following solution to the question:

```
g = tf.Graph()
with g.as_default():

    # Create model
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(...) 
    x = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, (1,1), padding='same')(inputs)
    # Done creating model

    # Optionally get graph operations
    ops = g.get_operations()
    for op in ops:
        print(op.name, op.type)

    # Save graph
    tf.io.write_graph(g.as_graph_def(), 'path', 'filename.pb', as_text=False)
```

Comment: This code defines the architecture of the model under `with g.as_default()`. But if I have a model object loaded already in memory using using `tensorflow.keras.models.load_model('checkpoint.h5')` ), how do I modify this code? Assume that this `with` block is in a function and we do not have access to the path of the `checkpoint.h5` file.